# How to change Log Level in a windows service

Tags: c#, log4net

I am running a website and a windows service . I am able to change at runtime the level of log of my Website using a page I made, and I would like to do the same for my windows service( ie: using a page to monitor the different levels of Log I am using in the service).

Would you have some tips and tricks to achieve that? Or should I resign and upload a new version of the log4net file every time I need to log things a bit more in details (this upload is a bit tricky and quite annoying to do)?

thanks for your ideas,

[EDIT]
UNfortunately none of the answer listed here are aimed at my problem. Mine is to access the log4net from a service located on a Machine A from  a WebSite running on a machine B. So that accessing the Web of MAchine A may allow me to change log level of service thread of Machine B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok only things I found, it to interface my service and Web Application to access the same table in the database, and make regular check to this table to change log level in servizio.

If someone has a better idea, I am all ears.

Answer (score 1):

If your windows service is using [ConfigureAndWatch](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch_overload_1.html) you should be able to edit the config file just like you do for your website with that page you made if you place the configuration file in a place that is accessible via the web page.

You will also have to change the path to the configuration file you load in your windows service but this should be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a config file and have your application pick up the changes.  The trick is that you cannot use the app.config/web.config file to do so.  Otherwise, it takes a reboot of your application before the changes will take place.  Here is a SO question that has a couple answers that might work:

[.net dynamically refresh app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272097/net-dynamically-refresh-app-config)

You can also make changes through code like so:

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2010/05/03/tweaking-log4net-settings-programmatically.aspx