# Need some clarification about app.config and user.config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

So I have been poking around both here on SO and google for the last few days for information about `app.config`.

I am writing a program that will need to generate SQL scripts using values entered by a user. Originally I was using `app.config` to store some default values to load into the program when it is first started up. This worked fine until I tried to store the new values back into the `app.config` file. This is when I found that `app.config` is read only and I should have been using `user.config`.

I have several questions that I can't seem to find the answers to:

1. Is it recommended to use `settings.Setting` to declare all the values that I want to use `app.config`? Or is entering them in by hand is enough?
2. I keep reading about how `user.config` overrides `app.config` settings. But when I update my `user.config` file, the program still reads from the original `app.config` file

This is from my wrapper class

```
public NameValueCollection ReadSettings(string sectionName)
{
        NameValueCollection scripts = null;
        try
        {
            //read in the current values from the section
            scripts = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName);
            if (scripts == null) throw new appConfigException(String.Format("The section {0} does not exists in app.config", sectionName));
        }catch (Exception e){
            //print out the log file
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy") + "log.txt");
            writer.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            writer.Close();
            //kill the application process so the user cannot advance further
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
        return scripts;
    }
```

is the `ConfigurationManager` supposed to automatically know to start reading from the `user.config`? Or do I need to change this section of code to reflect that?

Comment: You are correct, and probably just need to refresh the section you want to read again, after writing it into your user.config file. See this post for how to reload a configuration section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179254/reloading-configuration-without-restarting-application-using-configurationmanage

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: It is easier to use Settings.settings instead of creating your own configuration file yourApp.config. Because using the first option you can access your properties just using Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty and with the app.config file instead you have to deal with ConfigurationManager object, and usually to access a property you need to know the name beforehand and it usually is hardcoded.

Question 2: Yes, you are right the app.config is different from Settings.setting. Because you could even create a new file temp.config which could also be used as a config file for your application.

Final question: Im not sure, but I don't think ConfigurationManager knows anything about that, just parse the app.config file.

Hope it helps.